# how to power on the pump on arduino

Tags: if-statement, arduino, arduino-c++

I want to make a project that can start the pump according to the following conditions

the pump 1 will on if "jaraak" less than 5

the pump 2 will on if "jaraak" more than 10

the pump 3 and 4 wiil on if "tdsvalue" less than 700

the pump 2 will on if "tdsvalue" more than 800

Is the code that I made correct, because in my code just pump 1 always on

```
if (jaraak <= 5)
    { antares.getInt("jaraak");
      antares.add("Tandon Aman, jarak air " , jaraak  );
      digitalWrite(pompa1, pompaON);
      digitalWrite(pompa2, pompaOFF);
      }

  if (jaraak >= 10) 
    { antares.getInt("jaraak");
      antares.add("Tandon Habis, jarak air " , jaraak  );
      digitalWrite(pompa1, pompaOFF);
      digitalWrite(pompa2, pompaON);
      }

  if (tdsValue < 700)
    { antares.getFloat("tdsValue");
      antares.add("\n Kepekatan Nutrisi (ppm)" , tdsValue  );
      {digitalWrite(pompa3, pompaON);
      digitalWrite(pompa4, pompaON);}
    }

  if (tdsValue > 800)
    { antares.getFloat("tdsValue");
      antares.add("\n Kepekatan Nutrisi (ppm)" , tdsValue  );
      digitalWrite(pompa3, pompaOFF);
      digitalWrite(pompa4, pompaOFF);
      digitalWrite(pompa2, pompaON);
    }
```

Comment: It isn't completely correct. You missed taking intermediate values into account. For instance, pump1 won't off if 5<jaraak<10

Comment: sorry, this is the newest
```
if (jaraak >= 5 && jaraak <10)
    { antares.getInt("jaraak");
      antares.add("Tandon Aman, jarak air " , jaraak  );
      digitalWrite(pompa1, pompaON);
      digitalWrite(pompa2, pompaOFF);
      }
```

Comment: don't add code in comments, improve your post... Arduino is programmed in C++ btw, knowing what language you're trying to program might help a lot

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't consider all the possible values of the variables. Consider this alternative:

```
if (jaraak < 5)   // You say: "the pump 1 will on if jaraak LESS than 5"
{                 //          "the pump 2 will on if jaraak MORE than 10" 
     // ...
     digitalWrite(pompa1, pompaON);
     digitalWrite(pompa2, pompaOFF);
}
else if (jaraak <= 10)  // <-- This is the case when  5 <= jaraak <= 10
{
     // ...
     digitalWrite(pompa1, pompaOFF);
     digitalWrite(pompa2, pompaOFF);
}
else                    // <-- This is the case when  jaraak > 10
{
     // ...
     digitalWrite(pompa1, pompaOFF);
     digitalWrite(pompa2, pompaON);
}
// The same for tdsvalue
```

Comment: for TDS condition like this?
if
else if
else
??